# Convert NSString in ASCII

Tags: objective-c, ascii

I have a string that looks like : 
    TestA==A;TestB==B
and I would like to format it so that it looks like :
    TestA%3D%3DA%3BTestB%3D%3DB
Thank you !

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I thought that something like
      theNewString = [theString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
could do the job, but no :(

Comment: `[@"TestA==A;TestB==B" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]]`?